# what's wrong with my Telegram query?

Tags: php, mysql, telegram, telegram-bot

```
public function createCityDialog() {

  $selectCity = "select name from telegramCity limit 6 offset 0";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $selectCity);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    /* 
    $this->buttons[] = [
      'text' => $row["name"]
    ];*/

    $this->buttons["text"] = $row["name"];
  }

  $this->telegramAPI->sendMessage($this->buttons, $this->chatID);
  $this->telegramAPI->api("sendMessage", [
    'chat_id' => $this->chatID,
    'text' => 'Виберіть місто',
    'reply_markup' => [
      'inline_keyboard' => [
        $this->buttons
      ]
    ]
  ]);
}
```

It returns an empty array. I think, it`s main reason why I send Message without inline buttons.

Comment: Step 1, diagnose. `var_dump($result)`

Comment: @Xorifelse, i can't use `var_dump`, but i tried to make this query in adminer

Comment: `$this->buttons["text"] = $row["name"];` need to be `$this->buttons["text"][] = $row["name"];// made it an array to hold all values not last-one`

Comment: @AlivetoDie That was my first thought as well, except with even 1 value `'inline_keyboard'` has something, yet it is empty.

Comment: change  like this and see any error is coming or not? `$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $selectCity) or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));`

Answer (score 1):

The query is failing because `name` is a [reserved MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

The fix would be to enclose the keyword like so:

```
$selectCity = "select `name` from telegramCity limit 6 offset 0";
```

There is also the part that if there are more results, its not being appended to the array.

```
$this->buttons["text"][] = $row["name"];
```

Your commented code would also do the job.

Comment: i have changed it. changed `name` to `districtName` and `$this->buttons["text"][] = $row["name"];`. Now this array looks like `{"text":[null,null,null,null,null,null]}`. But it isn`t empty :D

Comment: I tried `$this->buttons[]["text"] = $row["name"];` and receive `[{"text":null},{"text":null},{"text":null},{"text":null},{"text":null},{"text":null}]`

Comment: It means that the value of `$row["name"]` is `null`. Perhaps to diagnose store `json_encode($row)` and look at the response to see what you need. I suppose that `$row["districtName"]` would fix it.

Comment: Yep, I fixed it and now receive right array, but can't send message with inlline buttons >< there are no errors